# Passing parameters from one component to another

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforce-id

How to pass parameters dynamically from one lightning component to another lightning component.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your question? Generally speaking you can find best practices here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G931jWBnxHU&feature=youtu.be&t=2238

Comment: if you want to redirect to another component in Lightning Experience use navigateToComponent() and pass parameters as given in example: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToComponent.htm